# Database not showing up in Webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get a database to show up in a table according to an assignment(this is a college course). I have followed the instructions to the letter but I can't get the table to show up on the webpage. From what I can tell the database seems to be working properly and the Webpage shows up as intended but the table is empty. Right no the assignment is just setting up the early part of the program but the instructions say this should be working.

```
<?php
    require_once 'login.php';
    $pdo = new PDO($attr, $user, $pass, $opts);

    // Get Pages via Get Request //

    $page = isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])  ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

    // Set Records to show per page //

    $results_per_page = 5;

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY c_id LIMIT :current_page, :results_per_page');
    $stmt->bindvalue(':current_page', ($page-1)*$results_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindvalue(':results_per_page', $results_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Fetch the Records //

    $contacts = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Get the total contacts //
    $num_contacts = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts')->fetchColumn();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Contact Directory</title>
        <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
        <style>
        <?php include "./styles.css" ?>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header><img src="Diamonds.png" alt="Diamonds">My Contact List</header>
        <nav>
            <div class="navtable">
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a href="placeholder.html">Placeholder</a></li> 
                <li><a href="placeholder2.html">Placeholder</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <content>
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Read Contacts
                <a href="/scripts/create.php" class="create-contact">Create Contact</a>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>#</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>Phone</td>
                            <td>Title</td>
                            <td>Created</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>   
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach($contacts as $contact): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php $contact['c_id']?></td>
                            <td><?php $contact['c_name']?></td>
                            <td><?php $contact['email']?></td>
                            <td><?php $contact['c_phone']?></td>
                            <td><?php $contact['title_id']?></td>
                            <td><?php $contact['created']?></td>
                            <td class="actions">
                                <a href="/scripts/update.php?c_id=<?php $contact['c_id']?>" class="edit" name="edit">Edit</a>
                                <a href="/scripts/delete.php?c_id=<?php $contact['c_id']?>" class="delete" name="delete"  onclick="returnconfirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="page_advance">
                    <?php if ($page >1): ?>
                    <a href="index.php?page=<?php $page-1?>">Next-></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($page*$results_per_page < $num_contacts): ?>
                    <a href="index.php?page=<?php $page+1?>"><-Prev</a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </content>
        <footer>
            <div class="copyright">
                <p>&copy; Copyright 2022 by Ian Sikes-Cook, this site is for a class project</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `From what I can tell the database is working properly` How can you tell this?

Comment: Is PHP pulling the data properly?

Comment: I accessed it in MySQL and everything seemed to be working correctly and the information was correct

Comment: the login.php has a function that states if it  connects to the database or if there is an error. Whenever I run it says the connection is successful

Comment: Okay, so the error is between MySQL and the table. Is PHP pulling it correctly? Maybe the connection is fine, but retrieving it is not. What does `$contacts` contain right after you set it?

Comment: There _is_ data in the database table, right?

Comment: Yes I have checked multiple times and there is data there and it is correct. FYI There are 6 records

Comment: @user1599011 **$contacts** should contain the records from the database.  '$contacts = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);'

Comment: Okay, it *should* contain the records from the database, but *does* it?

Comment: Forgive me but I am new at this how would I check that?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with php, but I would start by learning `var_dump()`.

Comment: Used **var_dump()** It confirmed that **$contacts** does contain the information from the database

Comment: You're missing echo in your tds. `<td><?php echo $contact['c_id']?></td>`, etc.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That Worked! dunno why the instructions left that out but it wouldn't be the first time I had to work outside of them.

Comment: @AceG maybe the instructions used the shorthand echo syntax? (e.g. `<?= $contact['c_id']?>`) Just a guess.